# What does the comma do when it's in front of dictionary being converted to a list

Tags: python

I have this dictionary named files
I was looking for a way to get the first key without looping I read some where to convert to list and use the list to get the value from the dictionary,

`files = {"file_1": "<PDF object>"}`

I did this `name = list(files)`
expected result `[file_1]`
but I made a typo and did this instead;
`name, = list(files)` *notice the comma in front of the name variable*
`result = file_1`
What exactly does the `,` do I have searched for this I am yet to get an answer is this in the official python documentation?

Comment: It's [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). Sequence unpacking takes an iterable and assigns it to one ore more variables. In this case, `list(files)` gets the keys associated with the dictionary, and `name, = list(files)` assigns the first key of files into `name`.

Comment: And if there was not exactly **one** element in `files`, this would raise a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, something like `a,b = 1,2` can be used to assign two variables values in one single like. Here a is being assigned the value of 1 and b is being assigned the value of 2.

It's the same as doing this,

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

In your case you wrote `name, = list(files)`. This is something similar to the example I gave but here you only passed one variable and one value instead of two like in my example.

Answer (score 1):

when you do

```
a, = [b]
```

then the left side is a tuple:

```
(a,) = [b]
```

which sets `a` to `b`.

Comment: I got type of <class 'str'> `objs = {'name_1': 2, 'name_2': 1}` `>>> name_one, name_two = list(objs)` `>>> name_one 'name_1' `  checking type =` >>> type(name_one) <class 'str'> `

Comment: @CynthiaOnyilimba which makes sense because 'name_one, name_two = list(objs)' is just like doing: 'name_one = "name_1"; name_two = "name_2"'